# dockstyle fill panel slides behind top/bottom docked panel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a form. It has a panel docked to the top and a panel docked to the bottom. The remainder of the form is a panel in the middle. I want it to expand to fill the remainder of my form so I set the dockstyle to FILL for this center panel. When I do this visually nothing jumps around but my resizing adorners move upward/downward behind my top and bottom docked panels. Now my resize adorners are the same size as the base form.

What am I doing wrong? My middle panel acts like it does not understand there is a boundary that is established by the top and bottom docked panels on the form. It just extends right past where I believe it should stop.

[image: A picture of this issue]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try clicking on the middle panel that is getting overlapped by the other panels to select it, then right-click it and select `Bring To Front` from the context menu to fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you use a `TableLayoutPanel`, with one column and three rows. Set the Anchor property for all your panels to LEFT+RIGHT+TOP+BOTTOM, then set the row heights as you want. Fixed for the top and bottom, and "100%" for the middle.

Comment: This seems a simple enough solution too. I'll find a way to use it in another project.